# 'Animation' does not contain a definition for 'TrackSetLoop' and no accessible extension method 'TrackSetLoop'

Tags: c#, godot4

I have a small project in godot game engine with C# and I want to create bottom tabbar with four icons with tab bar highlight" animation, my example code is like that;

**Tab.cs:**

```
 using Godot;
 using System;

 public partial class Tab : Node {
private AnimationPlayer _animationPlayer;

public override void _Ready() {
    _animationPlayer = GetNode<AnimationPlayer>("TabBarAnimationPlayer");

    // Create animations for each tab
    CreateHighlightAnimation("HighlightStore", "res://Scenes/One.tscn");
    CreateHighlightAnimation("HighlightSettings", "res://Scenes/Two.tscn");
    CreateHighlightAnimation("HighlightHome", "res://Scenes/Three.tscn");
    CreateHighlightAnimation("HighlightLeader", "res://Scenes/Four.tscn");
}

private void _on_texture_button_pressed() {
    GetTree().ChangeSceneToFile("res://Scenes/One.tscn");
    _animationPlayer.Play("HighlightStore");
}

private void _on_texture_button_2_pressed() {
    GetTree().ChangeSceneToFile("res://Scenes/Two.tscn");
    _animationPlayer.Play("HighlightSettings");
}

private void _on_texture_button_3_pressed() {
    GetTree().ChangeSceneToFile("res://Scenes/Three.tscn");
    _animationPlayer.Play("HighlightHome");
}

private void _on_texture_button_4_pressed() {
    GetTree().ChangeSceneToFile("res://Scenes/Four.tscn");
    _animationPlayer.Play("HighlightLeader");
}

 private void CreateHighlightAnimation(string animationName, string scenePath)
  {
   var animation = new Animation();
   animation.Length = 0.5f; // Duration of the animation in seconds

// Assuming you have a TextureButton node for each tab with a modulate property
var tabButton = GetNode<TextureButton>(scenePath);
var tabPath = tabButton.GetPath();

// Add a track for the property you want to animate (e.g., modulate for color)
var trackIndex = animation.AddTrack(Animation.TrackType.Value);
animation.TrackSetPath(trackIndex, tabPath + ":modulate");
animation.TrackInsertKey(trackIndex, 0.0f, new Color(1, 1, 1, 1)); // Normal color
animation.TrackInsertKey(trackIndex, 0.5f, new Color(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1)); // Highlighted color
animation.TrackSetLoop(trackIndex, true); // Set the loop property on the track

// Add the animation track to the AnimationPlayer
_animationPlayer.AddAnimationTrack(animationName, animation);
 }

 }
```

when debug the project it is throw an error like that

> 'Animation' does not contain a definition for 'TrackSetLoop' and no
> accessible extension method 'TrackSetLoop' accepting a first argument
> of type 'Animation' could be found

I did not find the what I missed in my codes, any idea will be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

The `Animation` should have a `LoopMode` property you can set, and it applies for the whole animation (it is not per track). *I haven't done this in C#, so I don't an example to share.*

Comment: Actually my all code not worki ng in godot 4 with C#, I do not know what I missed